# AFJSONRequestOperation / AFHTTPClient fetching old data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http, afnetworking

So all I'm trying to do is serve up a .json file somewhere (I've tried both my own personal server, and also on AppFog), then performing a GET request using AFJSONRequestOperation on the iOS platform. My code to do this request is as follows:

```
AFHTTPClient *aclient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURL]];
NSURLRequest *request = [aclient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                           path:@"voucher.json"
                                     parameters:nil];

AFJSONRequestOperation *op = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", (NSString *)responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[op start];
```

The problem here is that say the .json file initially contained an array of 2 strings. The above code would fetch these objects just fine. Then if I edited the .json file with another 3 strings, rerunning the code would continue to fetch only the 2 old strings.

**Only 10-15 minutes after I made the change to the .json file will a refresh give me the updated data.** At first I thought this was a caching issue, but setting [client setCachingPolicy:] didn't make any difference.

This issue is present whether I host my .json file on my static server, or running in a Node express server on AppFog. **It just keeps returning an old version of the resource requested.**

I'm really puzzled about this: so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url request is not cacheing the data. I had to implement the following so I would get new json data each time a fetch was made.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:5];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a caching issue - you could change the cache policy on the request or append something onto the query string, like the current time.

To do this you could use something like:

```
[aclient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                      path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"voucher.json?%@", [NSDate date]]
                parameters:nil];
```